# Azure Functions- is the entire request logged by default?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-log-analytics

Very new to Azure functions and not a professional developer. I created an Azure function with powershell code and it works as expected in testing: receives a request from a candidate tracking system and then creates an issue in Jira.

The issue: the function receives sensitive data from the CTS that can't be restricted on that side. Thus I need to verify that I'm not unintentionally logging this anywhere the function would log to by default. I don't need to worry about what *could* be turned on to potentially log.

Thanks

I've checked Kudu logfiles area, insight analytics and log analytics and I can't see anything that obviously logs the entire request body but I'm so new to Azure Functions I fear I may be missing something.

Comment: No, you should be fine. The only time the contents of the payload would be logged is if you explicitly told it to write something out to the log. Otherwise, just the invocation is logged.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Skin. In my mind it makes sense as it's potentially PII discoverable for regs like GDPR, HIPPA etc. That shouldn't hang around in odd places.